# Подключение к android exchange

Tags: android, exchange

Появилась задача подключиться к exchange и вытянуть задачи. Может, у кого есть какие идеи, как это лучше сделать? =) Т.е. я как бы уже все знаю, но может у кого то есть свои идеи или опыт в таких задачах...

Comment: Ну раз знаешь, зачем спрашиваешь?

Comment: Знаю подходы, страшно за них браться, может, кто-то панацею подскажет?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тема [обсуждалась](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739921/are-there-any-api-to-integrate-microsoft-exchange-server-with-java-application-f) в StackOverflow

Вариантов много, но я бы все таки рекомендовал **родной** (то есть рекомендованный Microsoft) способ - через [веб сервисы EWS Java](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi)